# My Recycler View is asking for List Adapter parameter while setting up adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I created a new Dialog fragment to display my listview in a alert dialog builder from [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/14/dialogfragments-android-simple-example/). My code was already working correctly when i was using normal listview instead of recycler view but as soon as i changed it to recycler view it is asking me to cast a parameter of List Adapter while setting the adapter to dialog builder.

Here is my DialogActivity

```
public class DialogActivity extends DialogFragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FoodList adapter;
private List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new FoodList(foodList);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flist, container, false);
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   return rootView;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });



    return alertDialogBuilder.create();

}
```

}

And here is my adapter

```
public class FoodList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodList.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
private List<Food> foodList;

public FoodList(List<Food> foodList) {
    this.foodList = foodList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.examplelistview, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.txtfield1.setText(food.getfield1());
    holder.txtfield2.setText(food.getfield2());
    holder.txtfield3.setText(food.getfield3());
    holder.txtfield4.setText(food.getfield4());

    /*
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_up_in);
        animation.setFillEnabled(true);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    */
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtfield1, txtfield2, txtfield3, txtfield4;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        txtfield1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfield1);
        txtfield2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfield2);
        txtfield3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfield3);
        txtfield4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfield4);
    }
}
```

Here is my flist.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

and i am calling dialog fragment in main activity like this

```
private void startNextActivity() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    DialogActivity testDialog = new DialogActivity();
    testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
    testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
}
```

while setting adapter in dialog builder it is giving me error to give a parameter of ListAdapter

```
alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

but in this case also it is giving me error that my custom adapter cannot be converted in List Adapter. I know i am doing some blunder but please can anyone help me!! 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't pass an adapter that you use with a RecyclerView to that dialog that you're trying to build as it expects an adapter designed for a ListView(adapters extending ListAdapter are meant to be use with children of AdapterView). Don't use setAdapter and simply set a listener yourself on the recycler row to do what you would do in the dialog's OnClickListener.

Comment: @Luksprog i want to call some data which orders to focus on markers based on the field name i have given on server. And do you mean i should only call on click listener without setting adapter to it? like you want me to remove this alertDialogBuilder.setAdapter(adapter) then how will the dialog know what is to displayed in it?